# Kotlin Spring boot @ConfigurationProperties for list

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to read the yaml config files using Kotlin and below is my code:
`application.yml`

```
message:
  messages:
    - name: abc
      type: aaa
      size: 10
    - name: xyz
      type: bbb
      size: 20
```

`MessageConfig.kt`

```
package com.example.demokotlin

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import java.math.BigDecimal

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "message")
@Configuration
class MessageConfig {
  lateinit var messages: List<Message>
}

class Message {
  lateinit var name: String
  lateinit var type: String
  lateinit var size: BigDecimal
}
```

Class to use the config:

```
package com.example.demokotlin

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class MessageService @Autowired constructor(private var messageConfig: MessageConfig) {

  fun createMessage(): String {
    println("in service........")
    println(messageConfig.messages[0].name)
    println(messageConfig.messages[0].type)
    println(messageConfig.messages[0].size)
    return "create a message......."
  }
}
```

Looks like if the yaml file has array/list, Kotlin can't read it properly but it works without array.

I have exactly the same code and works for Java. Something wrong with my Kotlin code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are encountering this [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762#issuecomment-311651689). Simply changing

```
lateinit var messages: List<Message>
```

to

```
var messages: MutableList<Message> = mutableListOf()
```

makes your code work. [Here is a full working example](https://github.com/snowe2010/SO-48325457-Answer).

#### edit (March 2019):

[As of SB 2.0.0.RC1 and Kotlin 1.2.20, you can use `lateinit` or a nullable `var`.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762#issuecomment-365634429)

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-kotlin.html#boot-features-kotlin-configuration-properties)

#### edit (May 2020):

[As of SB 2.2.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kotlin-configuration-properties) you can use `@ConstructorBinding` along with `@ConfigurationProperties` to set `val` properties on a `data class`.

Using the original class as an example, you can now write it like so:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "message")
data class MessageConfig(val messages: List<Message>) {
  data class Message(
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val size: BigDecimal
  )
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me so much. Thank you.

Comment: Is Fixed in Kotlin 1.3.11 with springboot 2.10,
sample provided in MessageConfig.kt works now

Comment: The `working example` really worked for me. The last `edit (May 2020)` did not. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Is Fixed in Kotlin 1.3.11 with spring-boot 2.10, sample provided in MessageConfig.kt works now

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "message")
class MessageConfig {
  lateinit var messages: List<Message>
}

class Message {
  lateinit var name: String
  lateinit var type: String
  lateinit var size: BigDecimal
}
```